# How to read another remote url android if the first url is not possible

Tags: java, android

I have this code and it works well to read a remote file, but I wonder how it would be possible and it would be like to read a second url url if the first fails.

That is, I read the first file url, if available, ok continued.
if you can not read the first url, then accesses the second url.

As you can add a second url "backup"
Thanks.

```
// Code

try {
            // Create a URL for the desired page
            URL url = new URL("http://myurl.com/archive.txt");

            // Read all the text returned by the server
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

            network1 = in.readLine();
            network2 = in.readLine();
            network3 = in.readLine();
            network4 = in.readLine();

            in.close();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }



        // Code



    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like this

```
String[] readUrl(String urlStr) throws Exception {
    URL url = new URL(urlStr);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
    String result = new String[4];
    for(i=0; i< 4; i++) {
        result[i] = in.readLine();
    }
    return result;
}

String[] tryMultipleUrls(String url1, String url2) {
   String result[] = null;
   try {
       result = readUrl(url1);
   }
   catch(Exception ex) {
       result = readUrl(url2);
   }
   return result;
}
```